# html5 canvas in jquery array syntax

Tags: jquery, canvas

am trying to not duplicate code by creating two query objects but not sure about the syntax. Any help would be appreciated

```
 var headers = $("h2.page-header");
var nav = $("ul#nav-main li a.active");
var links = [headers, nav];

    links.each(function() {
        var linkWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        var canvas = $("<canvas></canvas>");
        canvas.attr({width: linkWidth, height: 48});
        var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

        ctx.save();
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(linkWidth, 45.0);
              ctx.lineTo(6.5, 46.3);
              ctx.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
              ctx.lineTo(linkWidth-2, 2.0);
              ctx.lineTo(linkWidth-4, 45.0);
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(27, 73, 218)";
              ctx.fill();
              ctx.restore();

        var image = canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/png");
        $(this).css({background: "url('"+image+"') no-repeat"});

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply you a simple CSS [grouping selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping):

```
var links = $("h2.page-header, ul#nav-main li a.active");
```

if, if you want to keep the two selectors separate use the [`.add()` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var links = $("h2.page-header").add("ul#nav-main li a.active");
```